# Avoid Thread Sleep Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, mockito, junit5

I have the below method which uses websocket connection to send request,

```
public void sendLoginRequest(){

            WebSocket webSocket = webSocketConnection.getSocketConnection();

            Thread.sleep(300 * 1000);

            JSONObject loginJson = new JSONObject();
            loginJson.put("username","test");

            webSocket.sendText(loginJson.toString());
    }
```

I have created my tested case with,

```
@Test
    public void testSendLoginRequest() {
        obj.sendLoginRequest();

    }
```

Due to Thread.sleep, it's waiting for 5 min. I'm just curious to control this flow, and make sure the data send to websocket. As far as i know verify method invokes on Mock object, but in this case how can i achieve it.

P.S: I use `com.refinitiv.qc.ert.infrastructure.socket.WebSocketConnection` API.

Comment: if you _really really_ need that sleep, externalize that property and override it in the tests. Or `mockStatic` on the `Thread::sleep`

Comment: yeah i really need to use that, sure i will try to externalize time.